# Android: basic java + array

Tags: android

This is a basic question - but i am new to Android and Java, so please help.
Am trying to retrive all the rows from a DB (SQLite) and show it on screen.
So far it is working fine for a simple retreive and show.

But now, i want to add logic. If a certain field in the array is equal to a value, then i want to perform some operation and then display that field on the screen.

In more detail
Bank table - has Bank Name, Bank Balance, Bank Currency.
I want to read Bank Currency in a variable, if it is USD, then display Bank Balance as it is. If it is INR, then i want to convert it Bank Balance * 55 and then display the new Balance.

Here is my current code

DB Helper

```
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
{
    // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
    // the database.
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    Cursor cursor;

    try
    {
        // ask the database object to create the cursor.
        cursor = db.query(
                BANKTABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{BANKTABLE_ROW_ID, BANKTABLE_BANKNAME, BANKTABLE_BALAMT, BANKTABLE_CURRENCY},
                null, null, null, null, null
        );

        // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
        // to the ArrayList.
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                dataList.add(cursor.getInt(2));
                dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));

                dataArrays.add(dataList);
            }
            // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e("DB Error in Retreive all", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
    // the database.
    return dataArrays;
}
```

and this is the java class where i am calling this array

```
    private void updateTable()
{


    // collect the current row information from the database

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = db.getAllRowsAsArrays();

    // iterate the ArrayList, create new rows each time and add them
    // to the table widget.

    for (int position=0; position < data.size(); position++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow= new TableRow(this);

        ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

        TextView bankNameN = new TextView(this);
        bankNameN.setText(row.get(1).toString());
        tableRow.addView(bankNameN);


        TextView balINRA = new TextView(this);
        balINRA.setText(row.get(2).toString());
        tableRow.addView(balINRA);


        dataTable.addView(tableRow);
    }
}
```

this is the simple code to extact the Bank Name and Amount as it is. I want to add logic for the IF ELSE.
Please guide me with the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code to display amount in balINRA

```
    TextView balINRA = new TextView(this);
    if(row.get(3).toString.equals("USD"))
    {
    balINRA.setText(String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(row.get(2).toString()))*55));
    }
    tableRow.addView(balINRA);
```

Comment: or you can also skip the conversion by using this line,balINRA.setText(String.valueOf(row.get(2)*55));

Comment: can you help me with another simple Java question. Now instead of hard coding the 55, i want to pull it out of another table. So i have called currencyTable(); inside the updateTable() above. How do i pass variables in between these two? Currency table has two field - CURRENCY and RATE. So if CURRENCY is USD, i want to populate variable "rate" with 55 or if it is GBP, it should be "rate" = 80 etc.

Comment: can u let me know the structure of another table which you have created.so that i can give u exact answer

Comment: cursor = db.query( CURTABLE_NAME, new String[]{CURTABLE_ROW_ID, CURTABLE_TYPE, CURTABLE_AMOUNT}, null, null, null, null, null ); I am fetching this as an array as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22039/discussion-between-jasma-and-mehul-joisar)